# Where do events in init.rc are initiated?

Tags: android, android-source

I have been trying to understand where do events in init.rc are initiated.

 `on fs 

   mount yaffs2 mtd@system /system


on property:vold.decrypt=trigger_reset_main

   class_reset main`

One thing I know is that events can be triggered using `trigger` in init.rc itself. Where do these events are initiated outside init.rc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all managed in init.c

The property system is a little bit complex.

There is a property service resident in init process. Init process maintains several name spaces of the properties. E.g. ro.xx, system.xx, persist.xx.

Property setter set the property via notifying the unix socket message. So init process knows every setting action and you can see from the code that there is a callback "property_changed" called every time when a property is set.

Comment: init.c calls action_for_each_trigger() for "fs" but what about "on property:vold.decrypt"? Also, I could not find any references to inotify in init.c code. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Sorry for the uncompleted answer before. I have just modified it. But this is a big topic which can not be elaborated too much here.

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer is helpful.